# Perfmon for SQL Server from local machine

Tags: sql-server-2008, perfmon

I'm following Brent Ozar's video  on [Benchmarking and Baselining](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/gg429821.aspx), and I've got a data collector set on my local machine set up to hit a remote sql server, but I can't get the collection to start.  I right click it to start and the perfmon window locks up for a second.  After it stops locking up it still hasn't started, but it's not giving me any error.  **I've got it running under my windows domain account that is an admin on the sql server.**

So, how can i get this working?

edit:

ok, i'm getting a windows security event for a logon failure when i try to run the collection.

> An account failed to log on.
>
> Subject:
>   Security ID:      SYSTEM
>   Account Name:     [Machine$]
>   Account Domain:       [DOMAIN]
>   Logon ID:     0x3e7
>
> Logon Type:           4
>
> Account For Which Logon Failed:
>   Security ID:      NULL SID 
>   Account Name:     [USERNAME]
>   Account Domain:       [DOMAIN]
>
> Failure Information:
>   Failure Reason:       The user has not been granted the requested logon
>   type at this machine.
>   Status:           0xc000015b
>   Sub Status:       0x0
>
> Process Information:
>   Caller Process ID:    0x434
>   Caller Process Name:  C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
>
> Network Information:  Workstation Name:   [MACHINE]
>   Source Network Address:   -
>   Source Port:      -
>
> Detailed Authentication Information:
>   Logon Process:        Advapi
>   Authentication Package:   Negotiate
>   Transited Services:   -   Package
>   Name (NTLM only): -
>   Key Length:       0
>
> This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on
>   the computer where access was attempted.
>
> The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which
>   requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the
>   Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or
>   Services.exe.
>
> The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested.
>   The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).
>
> The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on
>   the system requested the logon.
>
> The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request
>   originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left
>   blank in some cases.
>
> The authentication information fields provide detailed information
>   about this specific logon request.
>     - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have
>   participated in this logon request.
>     - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM
>   protocols.
>     - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This
>   will be 0 if no session key was requested.

[MACHINE] is my computer, [DOMAIN] is our domain, and [USERNAME] is my username.

Comment: Anything reported in the event logs on your local machine?

Comment: @Mark Storey-Smith, i'm not seeing anything that sticks out.

Comment: ok, @Mark Storey-Smith, i lied.  i'll update my question with the task that's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logon type 4 is as batch.  The account's missing the "Log on as a batch job" permission on the target server.

The `Administrators` group is in this policy by default, but is likely being overridden by a domain Group Policy Object.

You'll want to check the resultant set of policy for `Computer\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Log on as a batch job` (and verify that `Deny log on as a batch job` doesn't have the user or any of the user's groups in it).

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Previous answer nonsense!

> The user has not been granted the requested logon type at this
>   machine.

Try explicitly granting "log on locally" rights to your domain account. Could the AD policy be denying the right to administrators?

Comment: it's already set to run as me.